# Angular6 - how can I test that an [ngClass] was applied?

Tags: angular, angular6, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

How can I write a test to verify that a certain [ngClass] was conditionally applied? Testing that either the style or the class name was applied will suffice.

HTML:

```
    <li (click)="toggleTodo.emit(todo.id)"
        [ngClass]="todo.completed ? 'task-complete' : 'task-incomplete'">
        {{ todo.text }}
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
    .task-complete {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }

    .task-incomplete {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

TEST:

```
    it('should style todo with no text decoration', () => {
    component.todo = todo;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(li.style.textDecoration).toBe('none');
  });

    it('should style todo with text decoration', () => {
    component.todo.completed = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(li.style.textDecoration).toBe('line-through');
  });
```

Expected - Tests pass.

Actual - expect(received).toBeTruthy(), Received: undefined.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
    it('should style todo with no text decoration', () => {
      component.todo = todo;
      fixture.detectChanges();

      const todoItem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('li'));
      expect(todoItem.classes['task-incomplete']).toBeTruthy();
  });

   it('should style todo with text decoration', () => {
     component.todo.completed = true;
     fixture.detectChanges();

     const todoItem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('li'));
     expect(todoItem.classes['task-complete']).toBeTruthy();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select your element using the query selector and verify class.

```
    it('should have the "task-complete" CSS class applied', () => {
    // Do whatever you need for setting the task complete
    ...

    // If you have multiple 'li' to check
     const listRows = this.queueTable.queryAll(By.css('li'));
     const clickedList = listRows[1];
     //find your li that was clicked or needs to be inspected 

     expect(clickedList.classes['task-complete']).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I used this answer as a starting point and found a slightly different solution that works for my case. It's posted.

Comment: my answer was assuming that you have multiple `li` in the html. anyway. good that it worked for you!